# Calling Webmethod for ajax datatable call with parameter

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

I need to call webMethod with parameters from the ajax DataTable function call. But with this code the control is not going to the WebMethod.

#### HTML:

```html
<table id="tblDetail" style="width:100%;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>SRNO</th>
            <th>TRNO</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Task Title</th>
            <th>Task Detail</th>
            <th>Start Date</th>
            <th>End Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

#### JavaScript:

```js
 function DisplayCof(srno) {
        var path = window.location.host;
        var pathname = location.pathname;
        var obj = {};


        obj.srno = $.trim(srno);
        //obj.cofno1 = $.trim(cofno);


        $("#tblDetail").DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(obj),
                url: "http://" + path + pathname + "/Data_Assignment_Task",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                "dataSrc": function (json) {
                    var msg = $.parseJSON(json.d);
                    return msg;
                }
                success: function (result) {
                    var data = $.parseJSON(result.d);
                    alert(data);
                }
            },
            "columns": [
                    { "data": "SRNO" },
                    { "data": "TRNO"},
                    { "data": "NAME" },
                    { "data": "TASKTITLE" },
                    { "data": "TASKDTL" },
                    { "data": "STARTDT" },
                    { "data": "ENDDT" }

            ]
        });

    }
```

#### C#:

```cs
[WebMethod]
public static string Data_Assignment_Task(string srno)
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MainDashboardDAC.GetAllRecById(srno));
    }
```

I also included the script manager to enable page methods.

```asp
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scm" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" />
```

Please tell me the problem in the code, or suggest the possible changes I have to make.

Comment: Anybody here please i need my answer soon..

Comment: have you added webmethod attribute on your `public static string Data_Assignment_Task(string srno)`

Comment: Yes it goes like this.

 [WebMethod]
        public static string Data_Assignment_Task(string srno)
        {

            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MainDashboardDAC.GetAllRecById(srno));

        }

Comment: Check above i changed the code.

Comment: suggestion: 1. separate the call to webmethod ajax and initialization of datatables. 2. use `location.href` instead of `path + pathname`

Comment: Initialization of Datatable depend upon the wedmethod where i need the value of parameter "srno" to get some specific data from database.

Comment: i suggest to separate them so u can really identify whether your webmethod is called. or your datatables init is correct or not. why not use call $.ajax, and on done callback, you init ur datatable.

Comment: 'location.href' also not working

Comment: could you show me the code to separate them.